# Specifying redirection options through a variable, in an exec command

Tags: shell-script, shell, io-redirection, exec

I want to be able to specify the redirection command/options via a variable (that I might set based on certain conditions, etc.). But when I run this bash script for example :

```
REDIRECT=">>test"
exec echo hi ${REDIRECT}
```

I get (via bash -x output) :

```
+ REDIRECT='>>test'
+ exec echo hi '>>test'
hi >>test
```

It looks like exec is placing the value of REDIRECT variable inside single quotes, instead of literally substituting its value.

How can I fix/get around this?

Comment: What's the reason you'd like to do this? If you want to change where the redirected output goes to, then you could instead just have an `outfile` variable and `exec echo hi >>$outfile`, or do you sometimes want to append and sometimes not?

Comment: I want to sometimes output to a file, and sometimes to stdout. (This would be controlled by an argument to the script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid using `eval`:

```
opt_file=""

# Command line parsing bit here, setting opt_file to a
# file name given by the user, or leaving it empty.

if [[ -z "$opt_file" ]]; then
  outfile="/dev/stdout"
else
  outfile="$opt_file"
fi

exec echo hi >>"$outfile"
```

A slightly shorter variant that does the same thing:

```
# (code that sets $opt_out to a filename, or not,
# and then...)

outfile=${opt_file:-/dev/stdout}
exec echo hi >>"$outfile"
```

Comment: when using that on linux, all the caveats about `/dev/stdout`, `/dev/fd/1`, `/proc/self/fd/1` being __not really__ the same thing as the standard out fd apply: `su otheruser -c 'echo OK; echo NOK >/dev/stdout'` => `bash: /dev/stdout: Permission denied`, `sh -c 'echo a; echo b >/dev/stdout' >file` => only writes `b` to `file`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to do this would be to use `eval` and all [classic caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/1081936) about `eval` would apply. That said, you could do something like this:

```
REDIRECT=">>test"
eval echo hi ${REDIRECT}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the whole of `stdout` to a file with the `exec` command
eg

```
exec >> outfile
```

Now any output will be sent to `outfile`.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >> outfile

echo start
echo hello
echo there
echo end
```

If we run this:

```
$ ./x

$ cat outfile 
start
hello
there
end

$ ./x

$ cat outfile
start
hello
there
end
start
hello
there
end
```

So we can see each execution appends.

This becomes simple to add in a test

```
if [ -n "$REDIRECT" ]
then
  exec >> $REDIRECT
fi
```