# $@ and exec weird behavior

Tags: bash

I have these two commands:

This runs as expected:

`bash -c '$@ 99<>/dev/tcp/0/9999' testname exec`

This returns the error that the program 99 wasn't found:

`bash -c '$@<>/dev/tcp/0/9999' testname exec 99`

I have verified that "$@" concatenates the parameters with the first character in the IFS which in my case is space.

Shouldn't those two commands generate the same result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying redirection options through a variable, in an exec command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298426/specifying-redirection-options-through-a-variable-in-an-exec-command)

Comment: No, the parameters in `$@` are not concatenated with the first value of `IFS`, except in some shells (not in bash!) and only in some special circumstances (eg. in `v=$@` or `case $@ in ...`, but _not_ in a case like yours).

Comment: Those commands should _not_ generate the same result, because redirections like `n<>` or `n>` (including the `n` fd number which, if present, is part of the syntax) are specially handled before any parameter expansion. Yours is another case of the "why doesn't `to='>'; echo yup $to /dev/null` redirect to `/dev/null`? which was probably already explained in a lot of Qs, but __not__ in the purported dupe.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that `$@` is not the same as `"$@"`.